# Stop React Webpack from writing in terminal

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, webpack

How can I stop this output from terminal? One week ago I created a ReactJS project with `npx create-react-app` and it works with no problem.
This is in the terminal of the first project:
[1st terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEopj.png)
(ignore the errors)
And this is in the terminal of my second project that I started today:
[2nd terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbVzL.png)
Which reupdates every time I save any file.
Both projects were started with `npm start`.
Is there every way I can stop VSCode from showing that in my terminal?

Comment: Why do you want to hide it? Is redirecting the output to `/dev/null` enough?

Comment: When I'm writing the css file for the website, I'm just trying stuff and I'm saving the file 10-20 times per minute to see if something changes, mainly because I'm not that good with how css puts items on the page, and that green color in the terminal just hurts my eyes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can silence output from any commands using shell redirection. Exact syntax varies per platform, but here's a few:

- CMD (windows): `npm start > nul`
- Powershell (windows): `npm start > $null`
- Linux: `npm start > /dev/null`